# ng build --prod not reflecting new changes in angular 8

Tags: angular

`ng build` is working with all new changes, but with `ng build --prod` only previous changes get reflected in the dist folder in angular 8.
Please help here.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the issue?

Comment: First Delete Dist Folder Then Try Again

Comment: Please add relevant tags to your question. And provide some more details about the question. With some code/error sample if possible

Answer (score 0):

delete dist folder which was created previous build then again try ng build --prod

Comment: clean cache of your browser then again open the site